# Chaining transitions so end of i trigger the start of i+1 : use .each("end", dothat)?

Tags: d3.js, kanjivg

I try to animate strokes of Chinese character one after an other. To do this *"at the end of i, start transition i+1"*, I use `each("end", animateSO(code,i+1))`, where animateSO thus callback itself with an increment.

```
// Animate strokes function
var animateSO = function(code, i){
var id= "#kvg\\:"+code+"-s"+i, 
    next=i+1;
var path = d3.select(id);
var totalLength = Math.ceil( path.node().getTotalLength() );
    console.log("i: "+i+" ; id: "+id+" ; lenght: "+totalLength+"; i++: "+next);
path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(totalLength*15)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
    .each("end", animateSO(code, next));
}
animateSO("07425", 1);
```

I expected `.each("end", animateSO(code, next))` to fire at the **end** of the current transition. But all transition are started together.

**How to, *"at the end of i, start transition i+1"* ?**

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/0v7jjpdd/4/

---

**EDIT:** final result http://jsfiddle.net/0v7jjpdd/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the call to `animateSO` into a function, otherwise it will be called together with the rest of the code:

```
.each("end", function() { animateSO(code, next) });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0v7jjpdd/5/).

Comment: Thanks Lars. I will handle the rest.